# Loop for values in a column in Python

Tags: python, pandas, loops

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 

df={'week':["Monday","Tuesday", "Monday", "Monday", "Tuesday"], 'Visits':[True, False, True, True, True]}
```

> I would like to make a function wich counts all the *"True" Visits and "False Visits"* for all the days of the column *"week"* and transform it in a percentage. Here is the result expected:[image]

I have tried :

```
u = np.unique(df.week)
j = len(u)
for j in df.week = u[0]:
x=(df['Visits']==True).value_counts()
print(x)
```

But that does not work unfortunatelly.
Thank you very much for you time and help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'week':["Monday","Tuesday", "Monday", "Monday", "Tuesday"], 
                   'Visits':[True, False, True, True, True]})

df = pd.crosstab(df['week'], df['Visits'], normalize=0).mul(100)
print(df)
Visits   False  True 
week                 
Monday     0.0  100.0
Tuesday   50.0   50.0
```

Comment: `df` of the original post is not a dataframe, need to add `df = pd.DataFrame({'week':["Monday","Tuesday", "Monday", "Monday", "Tuesday"], 'Visits':[True, False, True, True, True]})`